# Returning an empty "content" array when the page has no elements

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, hal-json

From the `AbstractRepositoryRestController#entitiesToResources` source:

```
if (page.getContent().isEmpty()) {
    return pagedResourcesAssembler.toEmptyResource(page, domainType, baseLink);
}
```

When a page has no elements, Spring Data REST puts into the `"content"` node an object with useless information (on my point of view) like:

```
"content": [
    {
        "relTargetType" : "my.company.ClassName",
        "collectionValue" : true,
        "value" : [ ]
    }
]
```

1. What's the idea/purpose of providing that information?
2. Is there any way to return an empty array `"content": []` when `page.getContent().isEmpty()`?
3. If it isn't possible, how then should clients handle such an unexpected format?

They parse the `content` iterating over it, and map each element to some domain entity. Since it isn't a domain entity, they fail. Fetching the first element and checking it on the existence of some specific fields (e.g. `relTargetType`) looks dirty, doesn't it?

Comment: did you solve this? Would help me aswell if you had a solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is something what i tried...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class TEST {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nullStr = null;
        List<String> nullListOrArray = null;
        List<String> emptyListOrArray = new ArrayList<>();

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("nullStr", nullStr);
        json.put("nullListOrArray", nullListOrArray);
        json.put("emptyListOrArray", emptyListOrArray);

        System.out.println(json.toString());
    }

}
```

Json string output: `{"nullStr":null,"nullListOrArray":null,"emptyListOrArray":[]}`

Comment: sorry, how is it related to the issue?

Comment: You asked how to return empty array so instead of array use list and initialise as new list and return it empty

Comment: I was asking how to do that by Spring Data serialisers when conditions are specific (a page has no elements)